# How to delete multiple topics in Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

Assuming that I have a number of topics with the same prefix, e.g:

```
giorgos-topic1
giorgos-topic2
giorgos-topic3
...
```

The command used for deleting a single topic (say `giorgos-topic1`) is the following:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic giorgos-topic1
```

Is it possible to delete multiple topics using a single command and possibly a regular expression/wildcard (e.g. `giorgos-*`) instead of typing all the topic names that need to be deleted one by one?

Comment: Does anyone what what should be the regex for digits only topic-names?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Yes you can use regex-like expressions when deleting topics with the `kafka-topics.sh` tool:

For example, to delete all topics starting with `giorgos-`:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --delete --topic 'giorgos-.*'
```

---

Using the Admin APIs, you can also delete several topics at once, see
[AdminClient.deleteTopics](http://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#deleteTopics-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: how about deleing multiple patterns, e.g., foo.* bar.* ?

Comment: It seems AdminClient.deleteTopics supports topic names instead of topic name patterns in its arguments. Is there a way to delete by patterns without querying in advance?

Answer (score 9):

In cases where regex is not possible we can use a comma seperated list of topic names for the deletion of topics.

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.0.0.160:2181 --delete --topic giorgos-topic1,giorgos-topic2,giorgos-topic3,...
```

Comment: Regex is always possible. For this example, `giorgos-topic[123]`. You can use OR too. `(some-topic|my-other-topic_1)`

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the accepted answer, the * wildcard needs to be preceded by '.'

In my experience:

--delete --topic '_confluent-controlcenter-5-3-1-1-.*' **works**

--delete --topic '_confluent-controlcenter-5-3-1-1-*'  **DOESNT work**

Note: I would've added this as a comment but don't have enough rep.

Comment: That's because it's a regular expression, not glob syntax. Also, the accepted answer did imply you needed a `.*`

Answer (score 3):

Please add *single quote* ('giorgos-.* ') if it complains like `no matches found: giorgos-.*`

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic 'giorgos-.*'
```

Answer (score 2):

Recent Kafka versions will remove the Zookeeper dependency and going forward you need to reference the brokers, through `--boostrap-server`:

```
kafka-topics \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 \
    --delete \
    --topic 'giorgos-.*'
```